# Trying to develop an excel Function to work out CGT (UK)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write out an excel formula to work out how much tax I should pay for CGT (UK).

So essentially I want one cell to work out the following:

```
IF Cell <50000, then (Cell/10) OR IF Cell >50001 AND <150000, then (Cell/20).
```

I got the first bit of logic to work: `=IF(M23 < 50000,(M21/10))`

But when I add the OR and the AND statement in, I get an error and I cannot for the life of me work out where i've gone wrong?

This is where i've got to:

```
=IF(OR(M23 < 50000, M23 > 50001 AND < 150000), (M23/10),(M23/20))
```

I think that's right in what i'm trying to achieve?

Comment: is it only the two either `/10` or `/20`? Then it would be: `=IF(M23 < 50000,M21/10,M21/20)`

Comment: Afraid not. So the way CGT works is: 

If Capital Gains = 50000 or less, you pay 10%
But if Capital Gains is between 50001 AND 150000, you pay 20%

Comment: @TimsKillerRabbit In order to not miss any values, you need to be clear on <= 50000 vs. < 50000 and > 50000 vs. > 50001. These are not the same. If it's 50000 and below, you want <= 50000 and > 50000. Using 50001 will likely cause issues.

Comment: @TimsKillerRabbit Scott's point is that if you only have two options, the logic can be simplified. If there are only two conditions you don't need to check for a value on the 2nd one. There will only be < 50000 and everything else. If you need to apply another rule for > 150000, you may as well add that even if you don't expect to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You need nested IFs() or an IFS().

```
=IF(M23 < 50000, M21/10, IF(M23 < 150000, M23/20, ""))
```

This says if M23 < 50,000, divide M21/10. If M23 is < 150,000, divide by M21/20. If neither of those cases are true, it will return an empty string. You don't nee an AND() condition for the 2nd test: if the first test for 50,000 fails you already know it's >= 50,000.

You could also use an IFS:

```
=IFS(M23 < 50000, M21/10, M23 < 150000, M23/20)
```

This will return an error if M23 is >= 150000 or is not a number. There are various ways to deal with the error, including adding 3rd condition to the IFS().

AND() is a function in Excel, not an operator. That's one of the reasons your function above wasn't working. Excel functions are not like a procedural language.